Stop my laptop from freezing/overheating when gaming
My laptop frequently overheats when I'm gaming. Some games it overheats in are VALORANT, Tom Clancy: The Division 2, The Finals, and Resident Evil 2. Not sure if this is connected or not, but Trackmania generally has poor, kinda fuzzy graphics, which most users don't have. Eligible games are automatically given HDR graphics. I generally put games on the least intensive graphics options. This doesn't change anything.
I have an EG-LP7 laptop model. I'm running Windows 11. My laptop is on a fan that runs constantly and is connected to a power bar, and when the laptop starts freezing/overheating, I turn on another fan facing it, but it doesn't help very much. Neither fan is powered by the laptop. The laptop's screen is displayed on a Samsung Odyssey Neo G8. My mouse and keyboard are connected to the laptop via Bluetooth. My headset is connected to the laptop via USB. My GPU is an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060. My driver version is 552.12, from NVIDIA. My laptop overheated before I got the monitor.
When I game, I don't have any other apps open, and no browser tabs, with a few exceptions; VALORANT automatically opens a stat tracker, and Discord overlay is automatically activated for certain games.
My laptop is always connected to a power source and is always connected to my monitor.
The only time my laptop ever overheats is when I'm gaming.
My laptop is connected to WiFi, not to an EtherNet cable.
My laptop never shuts off, just freezes a lot, lags a lot, and overheats.

What is the specific model? THX doesn't make laptops, so that link isn't super helpful. What temp(s) does your laptop reach when you say it "overheats"? It sounds as though you've done what you can to make sure the laptop is getting enough air, but the remaining factors are the capability of your laptop's own cooling system. Don't use "canned air", but you can carefully inspect the laptop's vents to make sure there is not dust or debris built up in them. Also, what is the temp of the room you're using the laptop in?

Open it up and clean the fans and cooling system of dust. Potentially replace thermal pad/pastes. Take it to a repair shop if you don't trust yourself to do it.

@music2myear My model is EG-LP7. I'm not sure what temp it gets to (and I won't be able to check that for a while). It's hot enough that if my hand is pretty cold, it warms up instantly, and is really close to being too hot to keep my hand on it. Kinda feels like a hot pad. My room is roughly 20 degrees C on average.
I'm not sure what you mean by canned air.

@Mokubai What is the thermal pad/pastes you refer to? How would I clean the fans/cooling system?

How do you know it is overheating ? Which part is overheating (CPU/GPU) ? Install something like HWInfo or CoreTemp. This will allow you to determine without a doubt if things are overheating and components start thermal throttling resulting in sluggish performance.
